# Slicing the first row of a dataframe and an additional row containing a date

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to take the first row of a dataframe (which will change weekly) and also a row containing a reference date (which is a constant) in order to perform a mathematical operation on them.

I can use `dplyr::slice()` to get the first row but any ideas on how to also return the additional row in the same call?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(x = c(10, 45, 65, 10),
                 dt = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01", tz = "GMT"))


slice(df, 1)
```

Ideally, I will get two rows back as a dataframe. The first row and the row specified by date.

Comment: If they are the same row, you want it returned twice?

Comment: Two different rows. Answer is below. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `dplyr::filter` because it lets you provide multiple conditions using an OR statment. We can then filter based on the desired criteria or based on a specific row number (generated by the `dplyr::row_number()` function):

```
 df %>%
     filter(x == 65 | row_number() == 1)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x dt                 
  <dbl> <dttm>             
1    10 2018-01-01 00:00:00
2    65 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `slice` by concatenating the the row index for first row ('1') with the row index got by `match`ing the value '65' from the 'x' column

```
df %>%
   slice(c(1, match(65, x)))
#    A tibble: 2 x 2
#     x dt                 
#  <dbl> <dttm>             
#1    10 2018-01-01 00:00:00
#2    65 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution.